# How to build Windows 8.1 app for Store (appxupload) in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Typically when I want to build Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 app for Store I open Visual Studio 2015 and in Solution Explorer I start **Store** -> **Create App Packages..** wizard.

I'd like to be able to **produce identical signed .appxupload packages using PowerShell** ideally just providing the target project file, target platform(s), build configuration and version number.

There is a [page for packaging and deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I just don't know what is the proper command order to use. There must be a simple solution for this standard task, right? Note I got Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Pro installed, so all prerequisites should be there.

And a bonus question, is it possible to run Windows App Certification Kit on this created package as well from PowerShell?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After log of digging I found the answer myself.
After associating the Project with Store and building app for Store using the Wizard and saving all changes it's then possible to build the store package again calling just 'msbuild' with the project/solution in a parameter.

I've described it in detail here:
https://www.suchan.cz/2015/09/building-windows-store-appxupload-packages-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

These commands work with VS2013 on a W8.1 machine and a W8.1 project. I haven't been able to verify them with VS2015/W10 yet. I suppose they should work, as long as the required W8.1 SDK is installed.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\makeappx.exe" pack /d "<BinDirOfProject>" /p "<BindirOfProject>\output\project.appx" /l
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\makecert.exe" /n "CN=tom" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e "01/01/2020" /sv "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.pvk" "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.cer"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\pvk2pfx.exe" /pvk "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.pvk" /pi "<Pwd>" /spc "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.cer" /pfx "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.pfx"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /fd SHA256 /a /f "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.pfx" /p "<Pwd>" "<BinDirOfProject>\output\project.appx"
certutil -addStore TrustedPeople "<BinDirOfProject>\output\key.cer"
```

You will be prompted to enter a private-public keypair when creating the certificate (makecert.exe, you can ofcourse use an existing certificate).
`<Pwd>` is your private key for this certificate.

Comment: Are you sure this works? The packages for store must be signed with appname_StoreKey.pfx that VS acquires when associating the app with Store.

Comment: The above solution works for self signing (we only use that as we only make enterprise apps). I'm not sure  how to acquire the certificate from the store; but once you have that. You should be able to use it with the signingtool in a similar fashion.