# Generate UWP .appxupload from command line VS15/W10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, uwp

We're having a build issue while building our UWP application and would love some ideas or if you have, solutions to our headaches!

Background:

We want to have a CI server generate a .appxupload file for store submission. This we have previously done using this command:

```
msbuild.exe App.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /m
```

**HOWEVER**, this is no longer generating an appxupload file. But it is successful in generating appxbundles.

**Our setup**:

- VisualStudio 2015 update 2
- appxupload is what we want
- AppxBundle is set as Always
- AppxPackageIsForStore is set to True
- The app is a minimum application. All I've done is: New Solution -> Blank -> Generate Store package from VS

**What works**:

- Generating appxbundle files using command line
- Generating appxupload files using Visual Studio (right click project -> Store)

**But... Have you tried...?**

Maybe, we've done a lot of searching around and tried things mentioned in a lot of them.
Some of the stuff we've read and tried includes:

- [appxupload package not being generated. Only test package is being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728729/appxupload-package-not-being-generated-only-test-package-is-being-generated)
- [How to build Windows 8.1 app for Store (appxupload) in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329223/how-to-build-windows-8-1-app-for-store-appxupload-in-powershell)
- https://www.suchan.cz/2015/09/building-windows-store-appxupload-packages-using-powershell/
- [How to generate .appxupload file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051980/how-to-generate-appxupload-file)
- [How to build Windows 10 appxupload(ready to submit to store) package by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688321/how-to-build-windows-10-appxuploadready-to-submit-to-store-package-by-command)
- [Creating app package from command line using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356517/creating-app-package-from-command-line-using-msbuild)

These are the different commands we've tried to generate an appxupload file.
All of them work and generate three appx files and one appxbundle. But none generate the wanted appxupload :(

```
msbuild App.sln /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;OutDir=C:/TEMP;BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=true

msbuild App.sln /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always /p:BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=true 

msbuild App.sln /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always /p:BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=True /p:AppxPackageIsForStore=True

MSBuild App.sln /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"

msbuild App.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /v:q /nologo

msbuild App.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:AppxPackageIsForStore=true /v:q /nologo

msbuild App.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=true /v:q /nologo

msbuild App.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:AppxPackageIsForStore=true /p:BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=true /v:q /nologo
```

I really hope someone will find this an interesting issue and come with anything that will lead us towards an solution!

THANK YOU in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you try “UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload” option.

I could create .appxupload file with this option.

MSBuild App.sln /p:Configuration=Release;UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/01/08/windows-store-app-projects-stopped-generating-the-appxupload-file-after-installing-vs-2015-update-1/

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I hope this information will be available on this page soon, for others doing something similar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh454036(v=vs.140).aspx#Create